# PDFs open in GIMP on Linux system

Tags: linux, pdf, gimp, evince

I installed evince on my Arch Linux system as a PDF reader, and everything was fine for a while. And then I installed GIMP. Since then, PDF files have been opening in GIMP. I've tried reinstalling evince, I've tried editing `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` , I've tried editing `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, but PDF files still open in GIMP by default.

Comment: What desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, ...) are you using?

Comment: What DE are you using (if any)? [OOPS!]

Comment: How are you opening the PDF?  Nautilus, command-line, browser, etc.?

Comment: I am using GNOME. (stupid 10 char limit)

Comment: @Matthew: Broswer and Nautilus, same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of [further research](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=496237) found that the offending file was `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.lst`

Comment: Nice one! Anyway...what desktop environment are you using?

Comment: GNOME, but the link applies to KDE, so they seem to be the same in this regard.

Comment: thanks for answer and question. i encountered this very problem lately but was to lazy to look into that matter. done now :)

Comment: Just a note. Under Kubuntu 18.04 I found the file in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` with `.list` instead of `.lst`...

Answer (score 0):

I found that Firefox uses the XDG standard, so using the XDG command line apps to set default applications solved the problem for me.

```
$ xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

This tells anything using XDG to use Evince to open `application/pdf` files.

There's more info where I found this, on the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open).